# Rust: error: "returns a value referencing data owned by the current function"

Tags: rust

I think this is a kind of common questions. I've read some solutions but my situation is a bit different...
It complains at line 8. However, I can't change the function signature of `new_b` as well as everything below the common line. They are all external packages.
So how can I design the function `new_a` to workaround?

```rust
fn main() {
    new_a();
}

fn new_a() -> A<'static> {
    let b = B {};
    A { c: new_b(&b) }
}

pub struct A<'a> {
    c: C<'a>,
}

// Below are exteral packages

fn new_b<'a>(b: &'a B) -> C<'a> {
    C { b: &b }
}

pub struct B {}
pub struct C<'a> {
    b: &'a B,
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=160e63f1300506472b7c1b0811b37453

Comment: `new_b` borrows `b`, so you can't use its return outside of the function you define `b` in.

Comment: you could create a value with a static lifetime by leaking it on the heap `let b = Box::leak(Box::new(B{}));`

Comment: Is your question "how can I create a `&'static _`"?

Comment: Sorry I would have explained more. This code is what I simplified from the original one. The `let b = B {}` can't be moved out of function `new_a`. The original code is at https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4218f15461d1e0f3ac1b3271328def01. The `let b = B {}` is equivalent to `line 29 let selector = Selector::parse(query).unwrap();`.

Comment: Either leak it, or store it in a `static`, or just embed the code in `main()`.